# Get List of Dates that falls with a month from a table that holds Transactions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core

Hello guys am here again,

Ok quick one, I have a Table to stores transactions alongside the date it was made.
Am working on a report to retrieve all transactions sum in each month in  the last 6 months.

currently i am using this to retrieve an array that holds last six months from current month.

```
//this guy gets the date of each month till the last 6 month
 DateTime[] lastSixMonths = Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i)).ToArray();

//here am loopin through each month and calling a service passing the month in loop as parameters
            foreach (var month in lastSixMonths)
            {
                var transAmountforthemonthinLoop = await _transactionsRepository.GetTransactionsAmountSumWithinAMonth(month);
                months.Add(month);
                monthSum.Add(transAmountforthemonthinLoop);
            }



//this is the service i am calling above
public async Task<double> GetTransactionsAmountSumWithinAMonth(DateTime month)
        {
            var monthString = month.ToString("MM/yyyy");
            var trans = await _context.Transactions.Where(c => c.DateCreated.Equals(month) && c.ResponseCode == "00").Select(c => c.Amount).ToListAsync();
            var sum = trans.Sum();
            return sum;
        }

this isnt working as expected
```

what i want forexample is.

```
if the first element in loop is say 2020/02/19

i want to go to my transactions table and sum all the transactions that has 2020/02 ie february as its months. and a responseCode of 00 which is successfl payment

Please any assistance will be appreciated.
``
this
```

Comment: What is the format of DateCreated in table Transactions? Is it just in MM/yyyy format or something else? could you post sample data?

Answer (score 0):

> if the first element in loop is say 2020/02/19
>
> i want to go to my transactions table and sum all the transactions that has 2020/02 ie february as its months. and a responseCode of 00 which is successfl payment

There's been a breaking change in EF3 .Starting with 3.0, EF Core only allows expressions in the top-level projection (the last Select() call in the query) to be evaluated on the client. When expressions in any other part of the query can't be converted to either SQL or a parameter, an exception is thrown.

To evaluate a predicate condition on the client, try to use below code in `GetTransactionsAmountSumWithinAMonth`

```
var trans =   _context.Transactions.AsNoTracking()
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .Where(c => (c.DateCreated.ToString("MM/yyyy") == monthString)&& (c.ResponseCode == "00"))
                      .Select(c => c.Amount)
                      .ToList();
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#restricted-client-evaluation